# HttpClient PostAsync doesn't send a proper request

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am learning on how to send request using C#

I want to send a request to the server of an airline to get a response about flight and their prices. 

In Postman I send the following JSON:

> {"flightList":[{"departureStation":"KUT","arrivalStation":"VIE","from":"2019-03-18","to":"2019-03-31"},{"departureStation":"VIE","arrivalStation":"KUT","from":"2019-04-01","to":"2019-05-05"}],"priceType":"wdc","adultCount":1,"childCount":0,"infantCount":0}

To this URL:

> https://be.wizzair.com/9.7.1/Api/search/timetable/

And it works like a charm. Although when to trying to implement it in my C# code using HttpClient I receive 404 Not Found error every time.

Here is the code I have atm:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Send("{\"flightList\":[{\"departureStation\":\"KUT\",\"arrivalStation\":\"VIE\",\"from\":\"2019-03-18\",\"to\":\"2019-03-31\"},{\"departureStation\":\"VIE\",\"arrivalStation\":\"KUT\",\"from\":\"2019-04-01\",\"to\":\"2019-05-05\"}],\"priceType\":\"wdc\",\"adultCount\":1,\"childCount\":0,\"infantCount\":0}",
            "https://be.wizzair.com/9.7.1/Api/search/timetable/");
    }


    public static async void Send(string body, string uri)
    {
        string myJson = body;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri,
                new StringContent(myJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        var requesturl = response.RequestMessage.Headers;
        Console.WriteLine("LOG: " + requesturl.ToString());

        var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(contents);
    }
```

I have tried getting the JSON from a text file cause I thought escape characters could be causing the issue but it didn't solve the problem.
Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Seems like a problem with your url. Otherwise, response code shouldn't have been 404, rather 400 or something...

Comment: [Code works flawlessly for me](https://imgur.com/a/Ry9JXlM).  Minor changes for fixing Tasks (because you shouldn't really return void from an Async method).

Comment: @ErikPhilips thanks for the input about Tasks. But I can't receive a proper response anyway. I used the very same code posted above and then I tried altering it according to your screenshot. Still the same error. Do you have an idea what could be causing it?